# Jasmine - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find') on argument

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having trouble when using .find() in an argument of a method, inside another method:

```
this.myObject.myArray = [{...},{...}];

public method1(): void {
   method2(this.myObject.myArray);
}

public method2(arrayArg: any[]) {
   arrayArg.find(...)
}
```

I have no idea how to test this with spyOn, I already have the definition in beforeEach of **this.myObject** as the following:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    myObjectMock = {
         myArray: []
    },

    ...
};
```

Any idea on how to tell Jasmine that there is a .find() method in the method2 arg?

Edit: Added my test in Jasmine

```
it('should ...', () => {
     controller.method1();
     expect(anotherObject).to.equal('another value');
})
```

Thanks!

Edit: The problem was not in Jasmine, but in the code, as stated by the selected answer!

Thank you all!

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more? is the problem with the code itself? or the tests you wrote? Can you please also include the code you write in your test file to mock the data besides just defining `myObjectMock`? Thanks!

Comment: hello, thank you for the concern, I added the test method, however, the selected answer was very helpful, it was a problem code-side and not in the test

Comment: yes, but clearer questions are important too. Clear questions will help more people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that to use find you first need to verify that the array is not undefined and also has a size greater than zero.

Try this:

```
public method2(arrayArg: any[]) {

   if (arrayArg && arrayArg.length > 0) {
      arrayArg.find(...)
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jose, voy a verificar! (I hope you speak spanish)

Comment: thank you, marked as the answer!

Comment: No te preocupes que hablo español... Espero te haya sido de utilidad. Saludos